# How to detect if Stripe's Checkout popup form failed to load by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm currently integrating Stripe's Checkout form on my website.
When user is viewing my website on Webview, via Facebook app for example.
I can't make the checkout popup to be displayed.
I just wanna know, is there a way to detect if the popup can show or not by javascript ? Then I'll show my custom form instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) defines a `StripeCheckout` global object, so you can simply test if `StripeCheckout` is undefined or not.